# 'char' followed by 'char' is illegal in stdint.h line 21

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I've been learning CPP a lot recently, this is my first GUI application. It was going well, got buttons and stuff to work.
But after doing little changes to storing and loading resources, VisualStudio starts through this collection of errors from the standard library

```
Error C2632 'char' followed by 'char' is illegal GUI stdint.h 21 
Error C2589 'unsigned': illegal token on right side of '::' GUI cstdint 12 
Error C2144 syntax error: 'char' should be preceded by ';' GUI cstdint 12 
Error C2873 'unknown-type': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration GUI cstdint 12 
Error C2589 'unsigned': illegal token on right side of '::' GUI cstdint 32 
Error C2144 syntax error: 'char' should be preceded by ';' GUI cstdint 32 
Error C2873 'unknown-type': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration GUI cstdint 32
```

These are all STD files, and I promise I haven't edited them.

The first error char followed by char is thrown on this line

```
typedef unsigned char      uint8_t;
```

And the rest of the errors are related to that as they are trying to use uint8_t.

Its been working away fine, then just on 1 compile, visual studio decided its own STD files have errors.

I'm not using stdint.h or cstdint (don't know if they are included automatically)

Includes

```
 #using <mscorlib.dll>
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <urlmon.h>
 #include <process.h> 
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <vcclr.h>
 #pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
 #pragma comment(lib, "Wininet.lib")
 #include <Wininet.h>
 #include <string>
```

Comment: Show wider code, for example near word GUI. Few problems can be guess

Comment: what GUI library do You use?

Comment: `#define uint8_t char` somewhere would be my guess.

Comment: Just system drawing. Also, GUI is the name of the project. https://i.imgur.com/8vlsHiC.png All the error source is within stdint.h line 21

Comment: Compilation failure within one resource does not necessarily mean the resource itself is corrupt! There might be some incompatible includes following one another (directly or indirectly), first one containing john's guess, second one is your cstdint...

Comment: Show *your* code (only the `#include` directives).

Comment: This is almost certainly a conflict between the system headers and some other header that tries to create its own definition of `uint8_t`. The way to solve this is to create a source file that only has the `#include` directives from the file that's giving these errors. Compile it to verify that the problem is still there, then start removing non-standard headers. When the error messages go away, you know who the culprit is.

Comment: Added all the includes

Comment: There is an option in VS to show all indirect includes. This is disabled per default because if enabled it will probably pollute your output window. It can be enabled per source file. I used it in the past when I tried to find out about similar colliding definitions in (indirectly) included header files. Sometimes, simply the "right" order of `#include`s is the solution.

Comment: Can you also show your compilation command? It is somewhere in the project compiler options dialog.